# Map docker cointainer folder to host folder - dev purposes

Tags: docker, docker-volume

Is there a way how to map/mount container folder to host folder? Like volumes but vice-versa.

Why?
I do have large project which including all the libraries has 0.5M files and folders. I have several of projects like this.
I would like to have project folder once on my disk (container) and not twice (local folder + cointainer)

I know that mounting folder from "closed" container to a host is from logic point of view nonsense - but again this is just for dev purposes.

I also know docker creates network interfaces. I'm not a net expert but maybe (in case that docker do not support this natively) there is a way how can I connect from my machine into container and map a folder to a folder (sshfs maybe)?

The dream is to have laptop with clean host OS instalation + docker. You pull up a docker image, run IDE, mount folders and start developing. No need of local instalation of NPM, Python/PHP/Perl/... nor their libraries.

This is just a vision but maybe I'm close to the reality than I can imagine.

Thanks

Comment: Why you can not use `volume` for this?

Comment: dir on local overlays dir in container - not vice versa